# Compilation error when installing on Drupal8

Tags: drupal-8, composer, aegir

Following [install guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/) I get fatal error at compilation tasks in `composer require civicrm/civicrm-core:'~5.35'`.

The setup is on [Aegir](https://docs.aegirproject.org/) with Drupal 8.9 and [drupal/recommended-project](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project/tree/8.9.x) composer template, having a relocated document root.

Is this error related to the setup above, or it's CiviCRM related?

Error log:

```
Compiling additional files (For full details, use verbose "-v" mode.)
Compile: Generate CCL wrapper functions
> @php -r 'require_once '\''/var/aegir/platforms/d8.9.13/vendor/autoload.php'\''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::template($GLOBALS["COMPOSER_COMPILE_TASK"]);'
WARNING: Failed to read compilation-task from COMPOSER_COMPILE_TASK. Please use "composer compile".
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid file reference (tpl-file=NULL) in /var/aegir/platforms/d8.9.13/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks/Template.php:62
Stack trace:
#0 /var/aegir/platforms/d8.9.13/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks/Template.php(21): CCL\Tasks\Template::assertFileField()
#1 /var/aegir/platforms/d8.9.13/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks.php(24): CCL\Tasks\Template::compile()
#2 Command line code(1): CCL\Tasks::template()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/aegir/platforms/d8.9.13/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks/Template.php on line 62
Script @php -r 'require_once '\''/var/aegir/platforms/d8.9.13/vendor/autoload.php'\''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::template($GLOBALS["COMPOSER_COMPILE_TASK"]);' handling the shell-runner event returned with error code 255
Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 255

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

In ComposerPassthru.php line 72:

  Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 255
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this compilation error is related to composer versions:

- Using default composer version of 1.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 produces this fatal error.
- Manually upgrading to composer 2.0 resolves this issue.